# Scraping website using node js using auth

Tags: node.js

```
      var getMatches = function(){
var sait = 'https://www.website.com'
request({ url: sait, jar:  true}, function(error, response, html){
if(!error){
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
var count =  ($('.TheMatch').length)
for(var i = 2; i< count + 2 ; i++){
    var live = ($('.TheMatch:nth-child('+i+') .LiveStatus').text())
    var nameMatch = ($('.TheMatch:nth-child('+i+') .MDxEventName').text())
    var time = ($('.TheMatch:nth-child('+i+') .DateTime').text().substring(8))
    var websiteCount = ($('.TheMatch:nth-child('+i+') .TotalBookies').text())
    if((websiteCount >= 25) && (live.length === 0) ){
        console.log('match ' + nameMatch)
        console.log('count Websites ' + websiteCount)
    }
}}})}
```

i want to make auth on this website and save the cookie how can i do it ? and save the cookie so everytime  i parse dont gonna need to log in ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did similar task. But problem is that it is always site specific. Anyway, the way to do it is to use request library to make a post request to website's auth endpoint. Then response object will contain appropriate cookies like sessionID or something. Then you save this cookie and do a new request to page you wanted from the beginning. Here is documentation about cookies in request module: https://github.com/request/request#requestcookie. That worked for me fine.

How to get:

```
request.post({ url: "website/signin",
                    form: {
                        login: 'login',
                        password: "password",
                        remember: 1
                    }
                }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
                    var cooka = false;
                    var cookies = httpResponse.headers['set-cookie'];
                    if (typeof cookies != "undefined") cooka = cookies[0];
                    if (typeof cooka != "undefined" && cooka != false) {
                        self.sessionId = cooka.substring(10, cooka.indexOf(";"));
                    } else {
                        return self.emit("error", "Can't get session id");
                    }
                });
```

How to set:

```
var options = { uri: "desired url" };
            var j = request.jar();
            if (worker.source == "coquette") {
                var cookie = request.cookie('PHPSESSID=' + worker.sessionId);
                j.setCookie(cookie, url);
                options.jar = j;
            }
            request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {

                } else {
               // work with body body
              }
          });
```

Comment: i get this error and cant find the worker http://s9.postimg.org/80ea6tr7j/Screen_Shot_2016_03_15_at_10_03_47_PM.png

Comment: Because it is copy/paste from my project. Even if I provided you a 99% of what you need, you, as a developer, should fix very simple errors yourself. self.sessionId and worker.sessionId are same thing, just change it to var sessionId;